# Syntax error at or near "UNION" in PostgreSql recursive query

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query, delete-row

I have many tables in the Database and they have foreign key relationship with some, I want to write a delete query which can delete data from all the tables based on some conditions.
In the below query I am getting syntax "error at or near UNION". if you know a better solution to achieve this issue, Feel free to share...

```
WITH RECURSIVE delete_query AS (
    DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = 1 RETURNING id
    UNION
    SELECT t.table_name, c.column_name
    FROM information_schema.table_constraints t
    JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage c ON t.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
    WHERE t.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
    AND c.table_name = delete_query.table_name
    AND c.column_name = delete_query.column_name
)
DELETE FROM delete_query
USING information_schema.columns c
WHERE delete_query.table_name = c.table_name
    AND delete_query.column_name = c.column_name
    AND c.table_schema = 'public';
```

Comment: You cannot `DELETE` in a recursive CTE.

Comment: From the manual: If RECURSIVE is specified, it allows a SELECT subquery to reference itself by name

Comment: Please let me know, if you know any alternative solution to delete data from a table and all its child tables data using some condition.

Comment: Look at the RECURSIVE workaround for DELETE here [WITH data modifying](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) and see if that be modified for your use.